# Using cron Chef cookbook to run a command every 30 mins

Tags: cron, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, logrotate

I am using the cron cookbook to run every 30 minutes in the following way:

```
cron_d 'logrotate_check' do
  minute  "*/30"
  command "logrotate -s /var/log/logstatus /etc/logrotate.d/consul_logs"
  user    'root'
end
```

Please let me know if it is correct?

Comment: This is really not the kind of question StackOverflow is for, just for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is fine. In the future, please just try it yourself rather than asking the internet and waiting 10 hours.

Comment: the fact that he asked, and you answered, just saved me from having to try it myself.